# Add OR and Like condition in findby()

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, conditional-statements, query-builder

```
$data = $this
        ->entityManager
        ->getRepository('io\V1\Rest\Advertisers\AdvertisersEntity')
        ->findBy(
            array('camapId' => '1465' , 'campName'=>'mytest')                
        );
```

here wanted to add the condition `camapId='1465' OR campName like '%mytest%'` 
rather than `camapId='1465' AND campName ='mytest'` 
 
so is there any way to achieve this?.

Answer (score 3):

You can make the search conditions in your repositories as complicated as you want if you use Doctrine2 DQL or the Doctrine2 QueryBuilder. You can read about this [here (DQL)](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html) and [here (QueryBuilder)](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/query-builder.html) in the Doctrine documentation.

There are a lot of examples online about how to use DQL and QueryBuilder to reach your result.

I think it will be something like:

```
$data = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
             ->where('a.camapId = 1465')
             ->orWhere('a.campName = mytest')
             ->getQuery()
             ->getResult();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $campIdsToFilter = $campIdsToFilterArray =array();
    $query = $this->entityManager->createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT a.campId FROM io\V1\Rest\Advertisers\AdvertisersEntity a where a.campName like'%mytest%' OR a.campId=1465");

    $campIdsToFilter = $query->getResult();
    foreach($campIdsToFilter as $ke=> $value){
    $campIdsToFilterArray[] =$value;

    }


    $data = $this
            ->entityManager
            ->getRepository('io\V1\Rest\Advertisers\AdvertisersEntity')
            ->findBy(
                array('campId' => $campIdsToFilterArray) , 
                $pageSize,  // limit
                $pageSize * ($page - 1) // offset              
            );
```